# How to properly align labels on top of bars when using positive and negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing a plot using `ggplot2` and a small dataframe `df`. My dataframe has a group variable `Letter` and two numeric variables `X` and `Y` (I include the `dput()` version of `df` at the end of this post).

My main issue appears when I try to align the labels of the bars on top. Because of my design, one variable needs to be showed to right side and the other to left side. That is why I multiply some values by -1. This is the code and output for my plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
#Plot
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Letter)) %>%
  mutate(value=ifelse(name=='X',value*-1,value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Letter,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black',alpha=0.7)+
  geom_text(aes(label=format(abs(value),big.mark = '.')),
            size=3,fontface='bold')+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(unique(df$Letter)))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) scales::comma(abs(x)),
                     breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(10))+
  coord_flip()
```

And the output:

[image]

As you can see the plot is fine but the problem is with the labels. In both left and right sides, a part of the label is inside the bar and the other is outside. I would like to have the labels in both sides at the top of each bar. I do not know if this is possible because some values are positive and other negatives. I have tried adding `hjust` to `geom_text()` and this only works for left side:

```
#Plot 1
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Letter)) %>%
  mutate(value=ifelse(name=='X',value*-1,value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Letter,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black',alpha=0.7)+
  geom_text(aes(label=format(abs(value),big.mark = '.')),
            size=3,fontface='bold',
            hjust=1)+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(unique(df$Letter)))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) scales::comma(abs(x)),
                     breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(10))+
  coord_flip()
```

Output:

[image]

I would like to find a way to have the labels on both sides aligned to the top of their respective bars.

Many thanks for the help. The `dput()` of my data is next:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Letter = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S"), 
    X = c(3099, 14201, 18901, 17351, 29498, 28928, 32284, 31536, 
    25334, 20008, 39242, 35856, 43317, 53765, 44652, 32876, 26142, 
    18567, 8836), Y = c(9482, 22669, 11159, 9506, 12113, 12805, 
    10570, 10199, 9190, 9217, 10674, 10894, 11986, 15664, 12793, 
    10552, 8050, 8609, 7717)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually set the `hjust` as an aesthetic variable, instead of giving all labels the same hjust value. Just give it a 1 for negative values and a 0 for positive values by doing `hjust = value < 0` *inside* the `aes` call - the resulting logical vector will be implicitly converted to 1s and 0s:

```r
df %>%
    pivot_longer(-c(Letter)) %>%
    mutate(value = ifelse(name == 'X', value * -1, value)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Letter, y = value, fill = name)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', color = 'black', alpha = 0.7) +
    geom_text(aes(label = format(abs(value), big.mark = '.'), hjust = value < 0),
              size = 3, fontface = 'bold') +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(unique(df$Letter))) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) scales::comma(abs(x)),
                       breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(10)) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: If only 0 were closer to the center, you could have just used `hjust="outward"`

Answer (score 2):

try to split geom_text by value type (>0,<0).  see below:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Letter)) %>%
  mutate(value=ifelse(name=='X',value*-1,value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Letter,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black',alpha=0.7)+
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(value>0), aes(label=format(abs(value),big.mark = '.')),
            size=3,fontface='bold',hjust=0)+
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(value<0), aes(label=format(abs(value),big.mark = '.')),
            size=3,fontface='bold',hjust=+1)+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(unique(df$Letter)))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) scales::comma(abs(x)),
                     breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(10))+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach, with an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Plot
df1 <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Letter)) %>%
  mutate(value=ifelse(name=='X',value*-1,value)) 
  
ggplot(df1, aes(x=Letter,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black',alpha=0.7)+
  geom_text(aes(label = format(value, big.mark = '.'),
            vjust = ifelse(value >= 0, 0.5, 0.5),
            hjust = ifelse(value>= 0, -0.05, 1.05)),
            size=3,fontface='bold') +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(unique(df$Letter)))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) scales::comma(abs(x)),
                     breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(10))+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]